# MongoDB equivalent of SQL greatest()

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am in the process of changing the underlaying database from a relational database to MongoDB, and I need to "recreate" the same semantics through MongoDB queries. All in all, this is going fine, with the exception of one thing: the SQL greatest() function:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE (GREATEST(FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_C, FIELD_D)
BETWEEN some_value AND some_value)
AND FIELD_E = another_value;
```

I cannot seem to find an equivalent to this GREATEST() function. I am aware that it is possible to achieve somewhat similar functionality by using the $cond operator, but as the GREATEST() function here is finding the greatest of 4 values, this would be a lot of conditinals. Is there any other way of achieving this? I have had a look at both the aggregation framework and mapReduce, but I can't seem to find anything directly similar in the aggregation framework and I am having a hard time understanding the mapReduce framework.

Is this even possible to achieve? I would assume that the answer is yes, but I cannot really seem to find a reasonable equivalent way of doing it.

Comment: It should be noted that greatest is not an SQL operator but in fact an oracle operator, it is not standard

Comment: @Sammaye you are absolutely correct here. However, even though greatest() is not part of the standard, it is very common that relational databases support it (oracle, mysql, postgresql, sqlite (though under the name MAX) from the top of my head).

Comment: The two are not quite the same however an easy way to get the max of something is to sort the result DESC on the field(s)

Comment: The fact that you want all fields makes the aggregation framework a difficult fit. Especially as your query isn't really aggregating. MapReduce would also be cumbersome.

Comment: The MongoDb way likely would be to precompute the "greatest" value upon document storage, rather than later at query time.

Comment: Yeah this would have to be pre-computed, I don't think a map reduce can actually this, at least not in a sane way. The aggregation framework could but that would lack any indexes in this case.

Comment: @WiredPrairie that is in fact a very good suggestion, one I did not think of myself. The fields part of the GREATEST() function will be updated multiple times, but it shouln't be a problem to recalculate this max value each time. It's a pretty cheap computation, and a bit easier to represent in Java I guess.

Comment: "*I am in the process of changing the underlaying database from a relational database to MongoDB*" For someone who worked with both technologies, this sounds like: "*I am in the process of converting a train into an aeroplane*". It would be easier to throw everything away and start from scratch.

Comment: @Philipp My wording might have been a bit weird, I am not fluent in english :) We are indeed starting from scratch, but the semantics (seen from the outside) needs to be the same for several reasons.

Comment: you can do this with mapreduce and you can do this with aggregation framework. strange that someone actually supposed you cannot do this with mapreduce which pretty much allows you to do any arbitrary thing assuming it can be expressed in JS.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

MongoDb doesn't currently have the equivalent to the `GREATEST` function. You could use a MapReduce, but it won't provide efficient immediate results. Additionally, you wouldn't effectively be able to return the other fields of the document. You'd need to do more than one query, or potentially duplicate all of the data. And, without running an update process for the results, it wouldn't be up to date as documents were modified, as a Map Reduce in MongoDb must be initiated manually.

The MongoDb aggregation framework wasn't intended for this pattern, and if it is possible, would result in a very lengthy pipeline. Also, it's currently limited to 16MB of results and doesn't easily return more than the fields you've aggregated. Returning `select *` requires a manual field projection, potentially more than once depending on the desired output.

Given that you want to return multiple fields, and the result isn't an aggregation, I'd suggest doing something far simpler:

Precompute the result of a call to the `greatest` function and store it in the document as a new field for easy access in a variety of queries.

Comment: but you *can* do this with MR and with agg framework and possibly via a regular find.

Comment: Sure, a MR could work, but that would seem unnecessarily complex and inefficient. And while one might be able to do it with a series of complex aggregation steps, especially if the number of fields grows, I wouldn't recommend it either. If any require the entire document to be returned and not just an aggregation, then they really aren't playing to MongoDb's strengths (as both are designed to return an aggregation of values and fields, not `select *`. You can't do this with a `find`. Fields can't be cross compared as is required by `greatest`.

Comment: Please leave a comment why you're down voting.

Answer (score 1):

If you query you quoted is what you are trying to replicate, you can take a different route...

You want to find all documents that the greatest of 4 values between a range (plus other criteria).

You can rephrase this as documents that all 4 values are below the upper limit and at least one is above the lower.
Something along the lines of:

```
find(
    {field_a:{$lt:some_upper_limit}
    ,field_b:{$lt:some_upper_limit}
    ,field_c:{$lt:some_upper_limit}
    ,field_d:{$lt:some_upper_limit}
    ,$or:
        [{field_a:{$gt:some_lower_limit}}
        ,{field_b:{$gt:some_lower_limit}}
        ,{field_c:{$gt:some_lower_limit}}
        ,{field_d:{$gt:some_lower_limit}}
        ]
    })
```

Probably a good idea to look at how indexes might help make this efficient, depending on the data, etc...

Comment: wouldn't you want to compare each field to both lower and upper together? otherwise there might be some combination where one field satisfies one condition and a different one the other condition? it would then not be technically the same as the original query.

Comment: The condition states is not about individual fields (A, B, C or D) being between the bounds. It's about the greatest. The keys is the the criteria is that ALL these must be below the upper limit (required for the greatest to be) and that ANY be over the lower limit (this would include the greatest in the case where there are more than 1). Otherwise said, the greatest will be in the bounds if and only if all values are below the upper bound and any value is above the lower bound...